# Can we block any specific webpage on network without blocking whole website?

Tags: linux, windows, proxy

I want to block a specific webpage on a site but not whole website.

For Example:

`www.example.com/about.html`  *should work fine*

`www.example.com/feedback.html` *should work fine*

*and every other page should work fine*

only `www.example.com/mypage.html` *should be redirected to* `www.example.com/home.php`

I just want to know that is it possible on windows or linux servers.

Note: I have no control over example.com

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean block access for incoming users and not for YOUR users connecting to the site(external)?

If the former:

Look into apache mod_rewrite. That'll do what you want. 
If you're not using apache, you may need to consult with someone else.

If the latter:

Look into setting up a proxy server. It'll depend on what OS you're using.

Comment: Remember, in this example, I am not owner of `www.example.com` and can't change anything in `example.com` content. I want to block specific page in my network without blocking whole site. I just want to know that is it possible ? Thanks

Comment: Yup. Like I said, you should look into proxying. My recommendation is to setup squid(Linux) between your Linux or Windows machines. Set a routing rule for that specific page and you should be set.

Answer (score 2):

We use pfsense for our gateway with squid proxy and squidguard installed to filter out domains/pages for specific users if you wish. Is that an option?

http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Setup_Squid_as_a_Transparent_Proxy